# Different backgroundimages for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use per-view backgroundImage in the UINavigationBar?
In the view loaded into the stack of UINavigationController, I tried :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
UINavigationItem* a = [self navigationItem];
[a setTitle:@"MY TITLE"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"mybar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

But the image is not shown at all.
Is it possible to change the navigation bar image for every uiview loaded into the stack as it is loaded? In other words, different background image for different uiview loaded in the navigationcontroller.

Comment: I tried to get a workaround about this and I ended up adding UIImageViews with my custom backgrounds to my navigation bar.

Comment: Can you answer with some sample code? However, fro my problem I solved it by putting the setBackgroundImage into the viewWillAppear method of the UIView loaded.

Comment: All I did was creating a UIImageView containing the background image and adding it to the navigation bar by `self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:`.